# React-table does not show valid page number when filter is applied again

Tags: reactjs, react-table

In my web application there is the table which displays **'50'** records on each page depending on the number of pages are present in the applied filter. Problem is, ex-> for a **1 JAN 2021** to **2 FEB 2021** there are 2 pages each displaying 50 records if I switch to 2 page it shows **2 of 2 pages** and then again I change the the filter but pagination of react table shows **2 of 2 pages** instead of **1 of 2 pages**

While the data show of **1 pages** according to the filter applied.

The whole code of component

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import { STORAGE_KEYS } from '../../constants/localStorageKeys';
import { PAGINATION_PROPS } from '../../constants/paginationProps';
import { APPOINTMENTS_MODAL_CONTENT } from '../../constants/status';
import {
    areDemographicsEnabled,
    areEmailOrTextRemindersEnabled,
    areEmailRemindersEnabled,
    areTextRemindersEnabled,
    getAppointmentTableData,
    hasPrecheckForms,
    isBalanceEnabled,
    isCopayEnabled,
    isInsuranceEnabled,
    isPrecheckEnabled,
    areBroadcastEnabled
} from './AppointmentsUtils';
import BalanceExpandedCell from './tableCells/BalanceExpandedCell';
import CopayExpandedCell from './tableCells/CopayExpandedCell';
import DemographicsExpandedCell from './tableCells/DemographicsExpandedCell';
import FormsExpandedCell from './tableCells/FormsExpandedCell';
import InsuranceExpandedCell from './tableCells/InsuranceExpandedCell';
import RemindersExpandedCell from './tableCells/RemindersExpandedCell';
import selectTableHOC from 'react-table/lib/hoc/selectTable';

const SelectTable = selectTableHOC(ReactTable);

class AppointmentsTable extends React.PureComponent {
    static propTypes = {
        clickedOnReminderStatusesViewAll: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        error: PropTypes.bool,
        fetchAppointments: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        filteredAppointments: PropTypes.array,
        onRowClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        pageNumber: PropTypes.number,
        practiceConfig: PropTypes.object,
        selectAll: PropTypes.bool,
        selectedAppointmentIds: PropTypes.array,
        toggleAll: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        toggleSelection: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        totalPages: PropTypes.number
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const { practiceConfig } = props;

        this.state = {
            isExpanded: false,
            expanded: _.fill(Array(PAGINATION_PROPS.PAGE_SIZE_VALUE), false),
            displayAllColumns:
                isPrecheckEnabled(practiceConfig) || areEmailOrTextRemindersEnabled(practiceConfig)
                    ? this.getColumnsVisibilitySettings()
                    : true
        };

        this.isSelected = this.isSelected.bind(this);
        this.toggleHeaderExpansion = this.toggleHeaderExpansion.bind(this);
        this.toggleColumnsVisibility = this.toggleColumnsVisibility.bind(this);
        this.getExpandedRowSubComponent = this.getExpandedRowSubComponent.bind(this);
        this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
        this.setRef = this.setRef.bind(this);
        this.getTdProps = this.getTdProps.bind(this);
        this.onExpandedChange = this.onExpandedChange.bind(this);
        this.onPatientNameClick = this.onPatientNameClick.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const { filteredAppointments } = this.props;

        if (filteredAppointments !== prevProps.filteredAppointments) {
            this.setRowsExpansion(this.state.isExpanded);
        }
    }

    getColumnsVisibilitySettings() {
        let displayAllColumns = true;
        const localStorageValue = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEYS.DISPLAY_ALL);

        if (localStorageValue != null) {
            displayAllColumns = JSON.parse(localStorageValue);
        }

        return displayAllColumns;
    }

    isSelected(id) {
        const { selectedAppointmentIds } = this.props;

        return selectedAppointmentIds.includes(id);
    }

    toggleHeaderExpansion() {
        const isExpanded = !this.state.isExpanded;

        this.setRowsExpansion(isExpanded);
        this.setState({ isExpanded });
    }

    setRowsExpansion(isExpanded) {
        const expanded = _.fill(Array(PAGINATION_PROPS.PAGE_SIZE_VALUE), isExpanded);

        if (!_.isEqual(expanded, this.state.expanded)) {
            this.setState({ expanded });
        }
    }

    toggleColumnsVisibility() {
        const displayAllColumns = !this.state.displayAllColumns;

        localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEYS.DISPLAY_ALL, displayAllColumns);
        this.setState({ displayAllColumns });
    }

    getExpandedRowPrecheckDiv(row) {
        const { practiceConfig } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="expanded-row">
                {areDemographicsEnabled(practiceConfig) && (
                    <DemographicsExpandedCell status={row.demographics} />
                )}

                {isInsuranceEnabled(practiceConfig) && (
                    <InsuranceExpandedCell
                        insuranceData={row.insurance}
                        clickedOnInsuranceDetails={() =>
                            this.props.onRowClick(
                                row._original,
                                APPOINTMENTS_MODAL_CONTENT.INSURANCE
                            )
                        }
                    />
                )}

                {isCopayEnabled(practiceConfig) && <CopayExpandedCell paymentData={row.copay} />}

                {isBalanceEnabled(practiceConfig) && (
                    <BalanceExpandedCell paymentData={row.balance} />
                )}

                {hasPrecheckForms(practiceConfig) && (
                    <FormsExpandedCell patientForms={_.get(row, 'forms', null)} />
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }

    getExpandedRowSubComponent({ original: appointment, row }) {
        const { clickedOnReminderStatusesViewAll, practiceConfig } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="rt-tr expanded-row">
                <div className="rt-td precheck-cell expander-cell" />
                {isPrecheckEnabled(practiceConfig) && this.getExpandedRowPrecheckDiv(row)}
                <div className="expanded-row">
                    {areEmailRemindersEnabled(practiceConfig) && (
                        <RemindersExpandedCell
                            appointment={appointment}
                            clickedOnViewAll={clickedOnReminderStatusesViewAll}
                            practiceConfig={practiceConfig}
                            type="email"
                        />
                    )}

                    {areTextRemindersEnabled(practiceConfig) && (
                        <RemindersExpandedCell
                            appointment={appointment}
                            clickedOnViewAll={clickedOnReminderStatusesViewAll}
                            practiceConfig={practiceConfig}
                            type="text"
                        />
                    )}
                    {areBroadcastEnabled(practiceConfig) && (
                        <div className="rt-td precheck-cell expanded-precheck-cell"></div>
                    )}
                    {areBroadcastEnabled(practiceConfig) && (
                        <div className="rt-td precheck-cell expanded-precheck-cell"></div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    fetchData(reactTableState) {
        const { pageNumber } = this.props;

        // This function gets called twice on table page change. Once for the page change itself,
        // and once for the data change. Don't re-fetch on data change. By the way, the table's
        // page is 0-based, but the prop's is 1-based.
        //
        // This function also gets called on initial load. In that case, the table's page is 0,
        // and the pageNumber prop is undefined.
        if (pageNumber !== reactTableState.page + 1) {
            this.props.fetchAppointments(reactTableState.page);
        }
    }

    setRef(r) {
        this.reactTable = r;
    }

    onPatientNameClick(rowInfo) {
        this.props.onRowClick(rowInfo.original, APPOINTMENTS_MODAL_CONTENT.ALL_PATIENT_DATA);
    }
    onTextClicked = rowInfo => {
        this.props.onRowClick(rowInfo.original, APPOINTMENTS_MODAL_CONTENT.BROADCASTTEXT);
    };

    onEmailClicked = rowInfo => {
        this.props.onRowClick(rowInfo.original, APPOINTMENTS_MODAL_CONTENT.BROADCASTMAIL);
    };

    getTdProps(_state, rowInfo, column) {
        const props = {};
        if (column.id === 'patientName') {
            props.onClick = () => this.onPatientNameClick(rowInfo);
        }
        if (column.id === 'textBroadcast') {
            props.onClick = () => this.onTextClicked(rowInfo);
        }
        if (column.id === 'emailBroadcast') {
            props.onClick = () => this.onEmailClicked(rowInfo);
        }
        return props;
    }

    onExpandedChange(_newExpanded, index) {
        const expanded = this.state.expanded.slice();
        expanded[index] = !expanded[index];
        this.setState({ expanded });
    }

    render() {
        const {
            error,
            filteredAppointments,
            pageNumber = 1,
            practiceConfig,
            selectAll,
            toggleAll,
            toggleSelection,
            totalPages = 1
        } = this.props;

        const data = error ? [] : filteredAppointments || [];
        const pages = error ? 0 : totalPages;
        const tableText = error
            ? 'Appointments are currently unavailable. Please try back later.'
            : 'There are no appointments for selected filters';

        const expandedRowSubComponent =
            isPrecheckEnabled(practiceConfig) || areEmailOrTextRemindersEnabled(practiceConfig)
                ? { SubComponent: this.getExpandedRowSubComponent }
                : {};

        const reactTableProps = {
            className: 'mf-appointments-table',
            columns: getAppointmentTableData(
                this.toggleHeaderExpansion,
                this.toggleColumnsVisibility,
                this.state.isExpanded,
                this.state.displayAllColumns,
                practiceConfig
            ),
            data,
            defaultPageSize: PAGINATION_PROPS.PAGE_SIZE_VALUE,
            expanded: this.state.expanded,
            getTdProps: this.getTdProps,
            id: 'appointmentsTable',
            loadingText: 'Loading...',
            manual: true, // informs React Table that you'll be handling sorting and pagination server-side
            minRows: 0,
            nextText: '',
            noDataText: tableText,
            ofText: 'of',
            onExpandedChange: this.onExpandedChange,
            onFetchData: this.fetchData, // Request new data when things change
            page: pageNumber - 1,
            pages,
            pageText: '',
            previousText: '',
            ref: this.setRef,
            rowsText: '',
            showPageSizeOptions: false,
            showPagination: pages > 1,
            showPaginationBottom: true,
            sortable: false,
            ...expandedRowSubComponent
        };

        const selectTableProps = {
            isSelected: this.isSelected,
            selectAll,
            selectType: 'checkbox',
            toggleAll,
            toggleSelection
        };
        return (
            <div>
                <SelectTable {...reactTableProps} {...selectTableProps} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AppointmentsTable;
```

The Pagination has an input in which you can edit the page

Comment: Not sure I can see enough code to tell you where to do this, but you often just have to manually set the current page back to 0 when the user does something that changes the results (i.e. changes filter, sorting, "per page", etc.).

Comment: @tmdesigned can you look at the whole code and let me know the problem

Comment: Are you basically saying that when you are on page 2 and you apply a filter that reduces your data on display to 1 page that the pagination still says 2?

Comment: Yes, Bottom of my react-table pagination shows 2 button and in middle of button there is an input type which show " showing 2 of 2 pages  " but data displayed is of 1 page